# Removing blank lines from text file after conversion of encoding vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a script that converts the encoding of a text file.
My text file has one blank line at the end, but after conversion I am getting 2 blank lines at the end of the file.
Can any one please help?
Below you would find my vbscript:

```
Const adTypeBinary          = 1
Const adTypeText            = 2
Const adSaveCreateNotExist  = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Const adWriteLine = 1
Const adReadLine = -2
Const adLF = 10
Const adCR = 13
Const adCRLF = -1
Set streamUTF8 = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Set streamASCII = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

set args = Wscript.arguments
strOutOne= args(0)

streamUTF8.Open
streamUTF8.Type = adTypeText
streamUTF8.LineSeparator = adCRLF
streamUTF8.Charset = "UTF-8"
streamUTF8.LoadFromFile = strOutOne

streamASCII.Open
streamASCII.Type = adTypeText
streamASCII.LineSeparator = adCRLF
streamASCII.CharSet = "us-ascii"

Do Until streamUTF8.EOS
streamASCII.WriteText streamUTF8.ReadText(adReadLine), adWriteLine
Loop
streamASCII.SaveToFile(strOutOne), adSaveCreateNotExist
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are specifying `adWriteLine`, as with every line the last line (your empty line) will be written and an extra line separator will be added, creating a 2nd extra line.

You could check if the line is blank before writing it to the ASCII stream:

```
sLine = streamUTF8.ReadText(adReadLine)
If Trim(sLine) <> "" Then streamASCII.WriteText sLine, adWriteLine
```

This will work if you don't have empty lines anywhere else in your file. Otherwise it will remove those too.

You can also consider reading the whole stream in one shot using `adReadAll` and then writing it all with `streamASCII.WriteText` and `adWriteChar`:

```
streamASCII.WriteText streamUTF8.ReadText(adReadAll), adWriteChar
```